# How to apply the css "display:block" to MudBlazor Tooltip?

Tags: blazor, tooltip, mudblazor

We have a tooltip and want to place an url inside which should be clickable. So the tooltip should stay if we hover over with the mouse. When we leave the tooltip window it should disappear.

Example how it works in google:

[image: Example of Google Spreadsheet]

In CSS it works with display:block but not with Tooltip of Mudblazor.

Comment: The problem with using 3rd-party stuff is that even if you fix the problem, you don't learn anything about Blazor or HTML.  Most important thing to learn-- Blazor just outputs plain ol' HTML.  So if you want to solve an HTML problem, don't limit yourself to asking a Blazor question.  See this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: In pure HTML with css this works with "display:block" but even if you add "important!" it won't work with Mudblazor...

Comment: This is why I never use 3rd-party components-- it's easy to make my own, but sometimes hard to figure out how other people's stuff works.  You'll have to use your browser's inspect tool to see exactly what is getting output to the browser, and make changes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two ways you can do this.

1. Override the `MudTooltip`'s default implementation of the `IsVisible` property by defining your own implementation of the `IsVisibleChanged` EventCallback. This involves creating multiple events for the child content tool and the tooltip content.
2. Create your own Tooltip ( you can still style it to match the `MudTooltip`).

This is easier shown via a demo -> [Mudblazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOmHOzEgyVXVFjmR)